# Strategy for deploying EF controlled Database

Tags: entity-framework

I have written an application using EF 6.0 in combination with an SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database. When a customer uses this application for the first time, it (the application) should create a database-file in a given path with some initital values. Also migrations should be allowed, for it is quite possible that the object model might change with future versions of the app.

Now I´m wondering what would be the best way to to deploy the DB on the users productive system. I could think of three ways:

1. I could create a DB-file with initial values and just copy it to the right place during installation process and use MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionInitializer in the app.
2. In the DbContext-Constructors (I have two contexts) I could check for an existing DB-file and use different Database-Initializers accordingly. Like a CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsInitializer with a seed method that creates initial data if no fiel is found and a MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionInitializer if the DB-file exists.
3. I could use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionInitializer always and in its "Seed"-method check for existing table entries and create them if they are not present.

Which of these ways is to be preferred or is there a better way I didn´t think of?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a desktop application so you might want to catch permissions errors about creating the database file at installation time (i.e. option 1) rather than run time, especially as in option 2 the database initialization is not an imperative command you're giving that you can put a try...catch around.

I don't think option 3 would work as the Seed method gets run after all the migrations, so surely the migrations will either have successfully run, in which case the tables don't need creating, or they will have failed as the DB doesn't exist and therefore your Seed method won't get run.

Comment: of course you´re right, method doesn´t work at all, because the MigrateToLatestDatabase-Initializer requires an existing database or probably the migrationhistory-table I assume. I think I will stick to method 1.